# Faceted navigation plugin problem installing

Tags: composer

I get the errors below in the Command Prompt when trying to install.

```
helloswish/craft-faceted-navigation
```

Does anyone know why this is not working?

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find a matching version of package helloswish/craft-faceted-navigation. Check the package spelling, your
  version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time you tried this, that plugin wasn't available on Packagist, hence it's not available to install from the command line (see the tip here in the plugin developer documentation: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/plugin-store.html#registering-your-plugin).

The plugin author has since added it on Packagist so your command should work now.